# Adding Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb leads to Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0,. The system cannot find the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin

I have a Asp.net webforms .net framework 4.5.2 and I use VS Version 16.11.5 and if I try to add Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb it leads to Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Packages.config has this entry

```
 <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

and web.config has

and

```
<add assembly="System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

I have tried removing these config entries but issue persists
I have also tried deleting temporary Asp.net files

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but consider upgrading to a newer runtime. The nuget package management in these old .NET Framework versions (particularly when still using packages.config) is seriously buggy.

Comment: what do you mean newer runtime

Comment: .NET 6.0, or at least .NET Framework 4.8 (+ change to packagereference)

Comment: @PMF mine is .NET framework 4.8 and still having this issue.

Comment: If the error persists when you remove these (obviously outdated) entries, try a clean rebuild. If that doesn't help, try figuring out whether you have a similar (direct or indirect) reference somewhere else in your project.

Comment: @PMF my take is Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb library is using some dependency of runtime 7.0.0 which starts giving me. When i uninstall it everything works fine. But i can't able to implement JWT without SystemWeb or can i?

Comment: I'm afraid but I'm not really familiar with the web service libraries. So I don't know whether there's any alternatives that work with .NET Framework.